Convergence of a certain bounded sequence
Let $(a_n)$ be bounded. Assume that $$a_{n+1} ≥ a_n - 2^{−n}$$ Then I need to show that $(a_n)$ is convergent.
I can rewrite the above inequality as $$a_n - a_{n+1} \leq 2^{-n}$$ from which we get that $$a_{n+1}\geq a_{1}-(\frac{1}{2}+\dots + \frac{1}{2^{n}})$$
After this, I am clueless about how to show that the sequence is monotonic.
Any form of hint would be sufficient.

Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem implies that the sequence has a convergent subsequence. Then it remains to show that the whole sequence actually converges to the same limit as this subsequence.

And what Wei said can be proved showing that $(a_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

@Wei kindly go ahead and write a short proof if possible

Let $b_n= a_n-2^{-(n-1)}.$ Then $$b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-2^{-n}\ge a_n-2\cdot 2^{-n}=b_n$$ Hence the sequence $b_n$ is increasing and bounded. Thus $b_n$ is convergent. Since $a_n=b_n+2^{-(n-1)}$ the sequence $a_n$ is convergent as well.
Remark The question can be generalized. Assume $c_n>0$ and $\sum c_n<\infty.$ Assume a sequence $a_n$ is bounded and $a_{n+1}\ge a_n-c_n.$ Then $a_n$ is convergent. Indeed let $r_n=\sum_{k=n}^\infty c_k.$ Consider $b_n=a_n-r_n.$ Then $$ b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-r_{n+1}\ge a_n-c_n-r_{n+1}=b_n$$ Thus $b_n$ is increasing and bounded, hence convergent. As $a_n=b_n+r_n$ the sequence $a_n$ is convergent as well.
